# Shopify customize order export csv file

Tags: shopify

I am trying to create a custom order export csv file from `Shopify`. I want customer id to be included in `shopify-exported-csv-file` for order.

Can I customize shopify csv export ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Not Possible`**. I had a discussion with `Shopify support` and they said it is a good feature for future. But right now, you can't customize the export of csv in `Shopify`.

Comment: No but you can customize it with your own scripting, which is the main point here. When stuck in a rut, sometimes you have to work a little harder to get back on the road.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! I do it in my App. I add two missing columns from the order export CSV Shopify produces. I add in the cost price of the item sold, and the product type. Strange things missing from Shopify data in the first place, but hey, with a teeny tiny bit of scripting code, you can add whatever you want to that data.

So I upload the Shopify data to my server, using the data in the CSV I decide what to add, and then I rewrite the data and voila! Beauty. I save it on Amazon S3 and include a link for downloading the data.

Comment: No No. I think you didn't get my point. My question is that when we click the export button on Order's page, Downloaded CSV should have customized fields. Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running a bit of code/PHP, [I have already done this](https://github.com/JayRizzo/Random_Scripts/blob/master/shopify_to_csv.php).

This script you save to your desktop and then call it like so:

```
php ~/Desktop/shopify_to_csv.php 'SHOPIFY_KEY' 'SHOPIFY_PASSWORD' 'SHOPIFY_NAME'
```

- Login to your Shopify
- Create A New Private App
- Grant the new App "Read Access" to "Products, Variants & Collections"
- Copy API_KEY & Password & Store Name from your Shopify Account.

and that is what you will use in the above command line using my script.  This will automatically convert special characters into HTML encoded references preventing any issue with using microsoft excel.

> Note: Where ever you run this code it will create the csv named after your SHOPIFY_NAME.